# Get CurrentPage/CurrentState with introduction_screen package in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, frameworks

I'm having trouble finding the CurrentPage/CurrentState index from a popular library called introduction_screen: ^3.0.2.

I want to replace the parameter of "globalFooter" with a certain condition.

As an example :

If the Intro screen is at the initial index (0), then display the Button widget. If not, then don't show any widgets.

```
globalFooter: isLastPage ? ElevatedButton() : Text(""),
```

How do I get the index of the CurrentPage/CurrentState? Previously, as a newbie in Flutter I had tried using "`introKey.currentState?.animateScroll(0)`" but that failed.

Answer (score 0):

`IntroductionScreen` has a parameter called `onChange` which takes a function of type `Function(int)`. Just wrap your introduction screen inside a stateful widget, create a bool field with `isLastPage` and pass a function to `onChange` where you set `isLastPage` to true if the given int equals the index of the last page.